# How to tell apart numeric scalars and string scalars in Perl?

Tags: string, perl, types, integer

Perl usually converts numeric to string values and vice versa transparently. Yet there must be something which allows e.g. `Data::Dumper` to discriminate between both, as in this example:

```
use Data::Dumper;
print Dumper('1', 1);

# output:
$VAR1 = '1';
$VAR2 = 1;
```

Is there a Perl function which allows me to discriminate in a similar way whether a scalar's value is stored as number or as string?

Comment: In what situation would you need to know the difference?

Comment: I want to build SQL conditions, and distinguish between values that need quoting and those which don't. Think `FOO = 00023` vs. `FOO = '00023'`.

Comment: Why not use placeholders and let your DBI module worry about quoting?

Comment: Yes, I would like that, but DBI is hidden by an abstraction layer in this codebase.

Comment: Well, that's silly. There are ways to determine or coerce variables to be what you want them to be, however, with so little information, it is very hard to give you advice.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

There's no way to find this out using pure perl. Data::Dumper uses a C library to achieve it. If forced to use Perl it doesn't discriminate strings from numbers if they look like decimal numbers.

```
use Data::Dumper;
$Data::Dumper::Useperl = 1;
print Dumper(['1',1])."\n";

#output
$VAR1 = [
          1,
          1
        ];
```

Comment: I accepted this one because it makes it clear that I won't be able to solve my problem. The other answers are still very helpful for their insight.

Comment: Actually, it can be achieved without writing C code or installing any modules. See my answer.

Comment: Wow, didn't know that, thank you! I'm curious then why it's not used in Data::Dumper, they used ordinary regexps for this purpose.

Answer (score 19):

A scalar has a number of different fields. When using Perl 5.8 or higher, Data::Dumper inspects if there's anything in the IV (integer value) field. Specifically, it uses something similar to the following:

```
use B qw( svref_2object SVf_IOK );

sub create_data_dumper_literal {
    my ($x) = @_;  # This copying is important as it "resolves" magic.
    return "undef" if !defined($x);

    my $sv = svref_2object(\$x);
    my $iok = $sv->FLAGS & SVf_IOK;
    return "$x" if $iok;

    $x =~ s/(['\\])/\\$1/g;
    return "'$x'";
}
```

Checks:

- Signed integer (IV): `($sv->FLAGS & SVf_IOK) && !($sv->FLAGS & SVf_IVisUV)`
- Unsigned integer (IV): `($sv->FLAGS & SVf_IOK) && ($sv->FLAGS & SVf_IVisUV)`
- Floating-point number (NV): `$sv->FLAGS & SVf_NOK`
- Downgraded string (PV): `($sv->FLAGS & SVf_POK) && !($sv->FLAGS & SVf_UTF8)`
- Upgraded string (PV): `($sv->FLAGS & SVf_POK) && ($sv->FLAGS & SVf_UTF8)`

You could use similar tricks. But keep in mind,

- It'll be very hard to stringify floating point numbers without loss.
- You need to properly escape certain bytes (e.g. NUL) in string literals.
- A scalar can have more than one value stored in it. For example, `!!0` contains a string (the empty string), a floating point number (`0`) and a signed integer (`0`). As you can see, the different values aren't even always equivalent. For a more dramatic example, check out the following:

  ```
    $ perl -E'open($fh, "non-existent"); say for 0+$!, "".$!;'
    2
    No such file or directory
  ```

Answer (score 16):

It is more complicated. Perl changes the internal representation of a variable depending on the context the variable is used in:

```
perl -MDevel::Peek -e '
    $x = 1;    print Dump $x;
    $x eq "a"; print Dump $x;
    $x .= q(); print Dump $x;
'
SV = IV(0x794c68) at 0x794c78
  REFCNT = 1
  FLAGS = (IOK,pIOK)
  IV = 1
SV = PVIV(0x7800b8) at 0x794c78
  REFCNT = 1
  FLAGS = (IOK,POK,pIOK,pPOK)
  IV = 1
  PV = 0x785320 "1"\0
  CUR = 1
  LEN = 16
SV = PVIV(0x7800b8) at 0x794c78
  REFCNT = 1
  FLAGS = (POK,pPOK)
  IV = 1
  PV = 0x785320 "1"\0
  CUR = 1
  LEN = 16
```

Answer (score 6):

Based on your comment that this is to determine whether quoting is needed for an SQL statement, I would say that the correct solution is to use placeholders, which are described in the DBI documentation.

As a rule, you should not interpolate variables directly in your query string.

Answer (score 4):

One simple solution that wasn't mentioned was Scalar::Util's [looks_like_number](https://metacpan.org/module/Scalar%3a%3aUtil#looks_like_number-EXPR).  Scalar::Util is a core module since 5.7.3 and looks_like_number uses the [perlapi](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlapi.html#looks_like_number) to determine if the scalar is numeric.

Answer (score 4):

The `autobox::universal` module, which comes with [autobox](https://metacpan.org/pod/autobox), provides a [`type`](https://metacpan.org/pod/autobox#EXPORTS) function which can be used for this purpose:

```perl
use autobox::universal qw(type);

say type("42");  # STRING
say type(42);    # INTEGER
say type(42.0);  # FLOAT 
say type(undef); # UNDEF
```

Answer (score 3):

When a variable is used as a number, that causes the variable to be presumed numeric in subsequent contexts.  However, the reverse isn't exactly true, as this example shows:

```
use Data::Dumper;

my $foo = '1';
print Dumper $foo;  #character
my $bar = $foo + 0;
print Dumper $foo;  #numeric
$bar = $foo . ' ';
print Dumper $foo;  #still numeric!
$foo = $foo . '';
print Dumper $foo;  #character
```

One might expect the third operation to put `$foo` back in a string context (reversing `$foo + 0`), but it does not.

If you want to *check whether something is a number*, the standard way is to use a regex.  What you check for varies based on what kind of number you want:

```
if ($foo =~ /^\d+$/)      { print "positive integer" }
if ($foo =~ /^-?\d+$/)    { print "integer"          }
if ($foo =~ /^\d+\.\d+$/) { print "Decimal"          }
```

And so on.

It is not generally useful to check how something is stored internally--you typically don't need to worry about this.  However, if you want to duplicate what Dumper is doing here, that's no problem:

```
if ((Dumper $foo) =~ /'/) {print "character";}
```

If the output of Dumper contains a single quote, that means it is showing a variable that is represented in string form.

Answer (score 3):

You might want to try [`Params::Util::_NUMBER`](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?Params%3a%3aUtil#_NUMBER_%24scalar):

```
use Params::Util qw<_NUMBER>;

unless ( _NUMBER( $scalar ) or $scalar =~ /^'.*'$/ ) { 
   $scalar =~ s/'/''/g;
   $scalar = "'$scalar'";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The following function returns true (1) if the input is numeric and false ("") if it is a string. The function also returns true (-1) if the input is a numeric Inf or NaN. Similar code can be found in the JSON::PP module.

```
sub is_numeric {
    my $value = shift;
    no warnings 'numeric';
    # string & "" -> ""
    # number & "" -> 0 (with warning)
    # nan and inf can detect as numbers, so check with * 0
    return unless length((my $dummy = "") & $value);
    return unless 0 + $value eq $value;
    return 1 if $value * 0 == 0;  # finite number
    return -1;                    # inf or nan
}
```

Answer (score -1):

I don't think there is perl function to find type of value. One can find type of DS(scalar,array,hash). Can use regex to find type of value.